# Parse MongoDB query to Java

Tags: java, mongodb, parsing

I need to perform the following MongoDB query in Java:

```java
db.ventas.aggregate([
{
    $sort: {"codArt._id": -1}
},
{
    $group:{
        _id: "$codArt._id",
        denominacion: {"$first": "$codArt.denominacion"},
        unidades: {"$sum": "$unidades"},
        importe: {"$first": {"$multiply": [{"$sum": "$unidades"}, "$codArt.pvp"]}},
        stock: {"$first": {"$subtract": ["$codArt.stock", "$unidades"]}}
    }
}
])
```

Is there any library, which can do it?
Unfortunately, I can't install MongoDB Compass.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like Hibernate, but no automatic translation is provided... you'll need to build your model. It will be useful though if you do not want to build the inner query or need some portability.

http://hibernate.org/ogm/

Answer (score 0):

There is a great tool to learn MongoDB Java Syntax and to work with MongoDB in general: [Studio 3T](https://studio3t.com), there you can generate a MongoDB query for the Java driver. Trial 30 days.

P.S. I'm not sure if this software requires admin rights to be installed.